# Boolean value '>=2' is not recognized

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema

I have a table with column1 as varchar datatype.
I am trying to update the table as :

```
UPDATE "DB"."SCHEMA"."TABLE" SET COLUMN1='>=2' WHERE COLUMN2='XXX';
```

I am getting error message as:

> Boolean value '>=2' is not recognized

COLUMN1 already has values like '>=3','>=2','>=1' . What is the reason behind this? and how can i update the column with '>=2' ?

Comment: Unless this is an error on your part, the value gets interpreted as a boolean by *someone*. Try obfuscating the value with CONCAT('>', '=', '2') or assigning to COLUMN1 e.g. the hex-decoding of the hex-encoding of '>=2'. Or you can do this in two steps: first assign ">=2KILROY", then assign the first three chars of COLUMN1 to COLUMN1 where COLUMN1 contains 'KILROY'.

Comment: Still not sure what the issue was. But i tried by setting the column value to NULL first then updating it. It worked. Thanks for the suggestion though !

Comment: Can you add table definition to see column behaviour.I tried with varchar on inserts and updates ,issue is not  getting replicated.